# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' IE Code

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Tried changing to IndexOf but this does not work still as I expect it to. I have converted my code from ES6 to ES5 but it doesnt appear as it should comparing chrome output to IE. What else am i missing? Added a snippet which has the javascript code to show you what I am trying to do. The below fails to run on IE but works on chrome and firefox.
I am trying to print out R T in both chrome and IE in binary. It is all done via javascript. See below images to identify problem. Looks like it lost something during the conversion between ES6 --> ES5 but still works fine on chrome.

```js
const mapping = {
    R: '1111111111111111111111000000111100000011110000001111111111101111111000110000110011000001101100000011',
    T: '1111111111111111111100001100000000110000000011000000001100000000110000000011000000001100000000110000'

};


// Grab the binary mapping of the letter and
// return some HTML
function binaryise(letter) {
    var arr = mapping[letter].split('');
    return arr.map(function (char) {
        return '<div class="' + (char === '0' ? 'zero' : 'one') + '">' + char + '</div>';
    }).join('');
}

// For each letter in the word create a 
// binary version and return it in a list-item container
function processWord(arr) {
    var items = arr.map(function (letter, i) {
        var binaryised = binaryise(letter);
        return '\n      <li class="binaryli" data-id=' + i + '>\n        <div class="containerbinary">' + binaryised + '</div>\n      </li>\n    ';
    }).join('');
    return '<ul class="binaryul">' + items + '</ul>';
}


// Get a random number that hasn't previously appeared

function getRandom(arr, memo) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return memo.indexOf(index) > 1 ? getRandom(arr, memo) : index;
}

// Once the html has been added to the page
// (all set with opacity to 0)
// iterate over the letters turning the
// opacity of each to 1
function showLetters(arr, memo) {
    memo = memo || [];
    if (memo.length !== arr.length) {
        var index = getRandom(arr, memo);
        var letter = arr[index];
        var el = document.querySelector('[data-id="' + index + '"]');
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.classList.add('show');
            memo.push(index);
            showLetters(arr, memo);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

var wordArr = 'RT'.toUpperCase().split('');

// Process all the letters of the word and add them
// to the page...
const html = processWord(wordArr);
output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

// ...then fade them in
showLetters(wordArr);
```

The below works with no syntax errors anymore but the images show the IE output is different from the chrome. The CHrome output displays 'RT' correctly in binary 1,0. The IE output just writes in lines and does not display it correctly. What might I be missing in the IE code? I believe it might be something in this line but cant be sure...return memo.indexOf(index) > 1 ? getRandom(arr, memo) : index;

Images to show you what happens in IE vs Chrome:

[image: What happens in IE seen in image below:]

[image: What happens in Chrome seen in image below]

Comment: Show your `.babelrc` file.

Comment: You can change to `memo.indexOf(index) > -1 ? ... : ...`

Comment: Are you loading `@babel/polyfill`?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support `Array.prototype.includes`.

Write your code in IE11-compatible way:

```
function getRandom(arr, memo) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return memo.indexOf(index) > -1 ? getRandom(arr, memo) : index;
}
```

The second problem of your code is the logic. Your function does not change `memo` or `arr` and thus if `memo` includes `arr` will cause an infinite recursion loop.

If you want Babel to transpile your code for you, you need to use `@babel/preset-env` package and define a `.babelrc` file in your project root:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": "last 2 versions"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This will still not fix the missing `Array.prototype.includes`. For that, and other missing prototype functionality, add `@babel/polyfill` to your package.json and import it at the very top of your Javascript entry point.

Comment: Updated question to show images - still does not work ( output is different in IE and Chrome after changing the getRandom function to ES5)

Comment: I have never used babel before - only used this https://babeljs.io/en/repl to convert it to ES5. Not sure how to transpile code for me in my solution